# How to prevent page navigation while using inspector in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web-inspector

I like to test HTML and CSS changes in the Chrome inspector, however, clicking on a button or link by mistake often results in losing all of my changes due to the view updating or navigating to a new page.

Without obviously not making mistakes, is there any way to prevent this happening via the inspector or any Chrome extension which could disable clicking on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout using Chrome Workspaces :

**[Edit Files With Workspaces](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/workspaces)** — Workspaces enable you to save a change that you make in Devtools to a local copy of the same file on your computer.